# Access property in Vue Draggable move method

Tags: vue.js, vue.draggable

How can I in the method access the properties of the item belonging to the moved element? I know evt.item.id is not working...

```
<draggable v-model="myarray" :move="onMove">
<div v-for="item in myarray" :key="item.id">

...

methods: {
onMove(evt){
     console.log(evt.item.id)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`item` that you use is only variable name that you use in `v-for`. You need to access `draggedContext.element` for this:

```js
methods: {
    onMove(evt) {
        console.log(evt.draggedContext.element.id)
    }
}
```